# How to use transform.localEularAngles in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am new at Unity and I am trying to make a simple 3D first person shooter. To do this I am trying to make a camera follow the mouse cursor. To do this I want to use set the localEularAngles according to the rotation generated by the mouse.

The following is the code of my CameraController script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maximumY = 360f;
    public float minimumY = -360f;
    public float maximumX = 60f;
    public float minimumX = -60f;

    public float sensitivityX = 15f;
    public float sensitivityY = 15f;

    public Camera cam;

    float rotationY;
    float rotationX;

    float offset;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        offset = cam.transform.position.y - transform.position.y;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        rotationY += Input.GetAxis  ("Mouse X") * sensitivityY;
        rotationX += Input.GetAxis  ("Mouse Y") * sensitivityX;

        rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);

        transform.localEularAngles = new Vector3(0, rotationY, 0);

        cam.transform.localEularAngles = new Vector3(-rotationX, rotationY, 0);

        cam.transform.position = new Vector3(cam.transform.position.x, 
        cam.transform.position.y + offset, cam.transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

The idea behind this is taken from the tutorial at this link: https://www.mvcode.com/lessons/first-person-camera-controls-jamie

However, when trying to compile I get the error: Assets\CameraController.cs(36,31): error CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'localEularAngles' and no accessible extension method 'localEularAngles' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The error occurs at both of the places that i use transform.localEularAngles. In fact, I have found no way to write transform.localEularAngles in a way that does compile, which has led me to believe that it might be deprecated, but it seems more likely that I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: Isn't it `localEulerAngles`? Note the `e` in `Euler`.

Comment: Hours spent on a god damn spelling error! You sir are my hero!

Comment: We've all been there! I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just a simple spelling mistake, should be `localEulerAngles`.

```cs
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, rotationY, 0);

cam.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationX, rotationY, 0);

cam.transform.position = new Vector3(cam.transform.position.x, 
cam.transform.position.y + offset, cam.transform.position.z);
```

Comment: [Should we answer or comment on a typo question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question)